# How to update security stamp of users in bulk? Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am updating users security stamp when a user is being deactivated. I can do this for one user like this.

```
await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);
```

I want to do this form multiple users, like 500 or may bee 100.
Is there any way I can do this in bulk?

I am using entity framework.

Comment: EF is not very good with bulk updates. Are you OK with executing SQL query?

Comment: Yes, but don't know how I'll call UpdateSecurityStampAsync(Id) on each user with sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security Stamp is a random string with no significant importance of the actual value, so you can just stuff new GUID there.

Best way to do it in bulk would be to execute SQL query:

```
update ApplicationUsers set SecurityStamp = NEWID()
```

You can specify `where` clause as needed to limit users you need to update, and most likely you'll need to change the name of the table to what you actually have in your DB.

There different ways to execute this query - you can do this with EF:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE ApplicationUsers........");
```

Or you can look into already recommended EF.Extended library - bulk update is possible without dipping into SQL.

Comment: accepted you answer for hint 'security stamp is just a random string' :)

Comment: @mfahadi Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Entity Framework Extended Library**.Which is the fastest way to do the update.Extended Library batch update eliminates the need to retrieve and load an entity before modifying it.So it is very fast.Try that.

Example from their doc :

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```

You can read more about it here : [**Entity Framework Extended Library**](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Comment: Actually I have to call this function for each user, can you tell how can I do that.

 UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId)